# What happens if I get a free tank, when my garage is already full?

Tags: world-of-tanks

After having played the beta back in the day, I returned after a long break, to see that my garage had changed. Some of my tanks had disappeared, and I had to buy them again. I also had a few new starter tanks, because WoT had introduced new lines. I assumed that WoT had removed some of my tanks to make room for the starter tanks.

However, after playing some more, WoT has given me a bunch or premium tanks as presents (most likely because I'm such a cool dude) – and I didn't see tanks disappearing. However, I do have 13 slots in my garage, which I'm fairly sure is more than standard.

So, my question is, when WoT hands out these free premium tanks during holidays or whatever, what happens if the garage is already chock full of metal cubes of death? Do they give you a new slot?

I am on the PC version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy additional garage slots for 300 gold apiece. According to multiple sources from the forums:

> Website = Premium Tank + Garage Slot + 100% Crew
>
> In-Game = Premium Tank + 100% Crew

[source](http://forum.worldoftanks.com/index.php?/topic/186109-garage-slot-included-with-premium-tank/)

> Premium tanks you buy in the gift shop usually (never seen it without) come with a garage slot. If you add up the gold and money, you will see that if they are not on sale, you pay for the 300 gold for the garage slot as well compared to the in-game store. Sometimes, they throw in the garage slot for free in the gift shop. So, if you have other things to do with your in-game gold, compare prices before buying in-game if there is a bundle in the gift shop.

[source](http://forum.worldoftanks.com/index.php?/topic/307618-premium-tank-garage-slot/)

[If you check out some of of their holiday bundles](http://worldoftanks.com/en/news/31/post-holiday-premium-shop/), they always come with a free garage slot for each tank.

Therefore it would only make sense that gifted freebie premium tanks come with this extra garage slot, and it comes with the slot regardless if you still have free slots.

Answer (score 2):

The premium tanks (no matter, free/gift or purchased) come with an automatic garage slot for them.

Comment: Always? Even if you have room for them in your garage? Or only if the garage is full?

Comment: Always, even if you have empty garage slots. If you don't care about the free tanks this is essentially the only free way to get additional garage slots. (However, note that if you sell these free tanks you are unlikely to ever be likely to buy them back, so be sure you are OK with that.)

Comment: Even the April Fools tank came with a free slot, and you got to keep the slot (but not the tank).